# How to get only the date part from date representation?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I Am trying to retrieve only the date part from date representation. My database server is phpmyadmin and i retrieve data through laravel controller.
I need to get only the date part, for example 2022-01-24 instead of 2022-01-24T18:30:00.000000Z from created_at column.

[image phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4xqw.png).

[image response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le5FX.png)

My web.php path is,

```
Route::get('/fetch/curriculumVitaes', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CurriculumVitaesController::class, 'index']);
```

I fetch the data through laravel controller and my function is index(),

```
public function index()
{     
   $curriculumVitaes =  CurriculumVitaes::where('deleted', '=', '0')->get();

   return $curriculumVitaes;
}
```

And I retrieve the data in frontend vue.js,

```
 <tr v-for="(curriculumVitae, index) in curriculumVitaes" :key="index">
    <td class="text-center">{{ index + 1 }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ curriculumVitae.created_at }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi SrihariSangeeth, 

what did you already try and what did not work?

Please have a look at these for further questions. :) 

[How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)
[How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: How could you solve your problem? Look at it step for step

- You want to achieve to have another date format as you got from the database.
- Let's assume you don't want to change your database.
- You get all CVs from the database into `$curriculumVitaes`

So you can either change it before you give it back to your Vue Application or change it in your Vue JS App. 

I personally would prefer it in PHP and I would look at the answered question: 
[Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: @Uwe yes.. thank you now I have an idea how to search ... sorry that I'm new to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with Laravel yet and I haven't used Vue.js. But I would think you could also use core php to resolve this. I've modified your code to what you see below. When I'm retrieving a date from the MySQL database that I want formatted, I use date('format', variable). In your case that would result in the code I have below. The format can be displayed a number of ways including: 'm/d/y', 'd/m/y', 'y/d/m', and more. m representing month, d representing day, and of course y representing year.

As @Uwe pointed out, my suggestion was php code inside the vue.js code. However, because I know you're using both php and vue.js, I still wonder if my modified solution below may work. Or somewhere in that ballpark.

```
<tr v-for="(curriculumVitae, index) in curriculumVitaes" :key="index">
    <td class="text-center">{{ index + 1 }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ <?php echo date("y/d/m", curriculumVitae.created_at); ?> }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi bluzman 

It seems not correct. There is a  bracket missing and it looks like PHP Code in the VueJS Code, which would not work. 

For a similar transformation, you would use something like moment.js or day.js

Comment: @Uwe you are correct. In my haste to help I forgot a closing parenthesis, and forgot I was adding a php solution inside vue.js code. Probably because the OP is using both php and vue.js. I will edit my suggestion, but as I admitted in my initial post, I'm not familiar with vue.js. So take my suggestion with a grain of salt so-to-speak.

Comment: No problem @bluzman :) 

But your solution will not work as there are some problems.

**1)** You are in a Vue JS `for loop` and it expects a variable and not an actual value between these brackets as it will replace the variable while being rendered in the browser.
-
**2)** As PHP is server-side rendered and VueJS Browser rendered you can't access the value from the JS, as it is not there yet.
-
**3)** The PHP code would not be rendered at all as it would cause an ` Undefined constant "curriculumVitae"` error.

Comment: try to add code not with the VueJS Code but with the PHP Code. 
Before he returns `return $curriculumVitaes;` you could walk with a foreach and change the date.

Answer (score 0):

****Use moment****

First we need to install moment npm package that will allow to change date format.

```
npm install moment
```

Now you can create a global function to set the format you want, to do so you must open the file `resources/js/app.js` and put the following code:

```
import moment from 'moment';

Vue.filter('formatDate', function(value) {
    if (value) {
        return moment(String(value)).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    }
});
```

Now in all your js components you can apply the format as follows:

```
{{ response.created_at | formatDate }}
```